# Mixing PHP with obfuscated JS

Tags: javascript, php, obfuscation

I am looking at obfuscating my JS code, however some parts of my JS code is generated from PHP logic.

One example would be the following:

```
<?php if ($somethingFromPHP == true){ ?>
        A_JS_Variable_Already_Obfuscated = true;
        A_JS_Function_Already_obfuscated('<?php echo json_encode($anotherThingFromPHP); ?>');
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see, there is a conflict with that code.

My PHP code is unaware of the obfuscated variable and function.

How would I solve this conflict?

Comment: What would you like to see as a desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend parsing the javascript with the PHP first, then running that file through a minifier and obfuscater. Or alternatively running the php separately, and taking the php output and inserting it into the javascript using commandline tools such as `sed` and `awk`, then running it through the minifier and obfuscater.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why any of the suggestions you've made would solve the conflict. If a variable is set during download of the page, how would my PHP code know what the obfuscated variable is in the first place?

Comment: All of my suggestions can be implemented before the page is rendered.